# Generador de enlace de WhatsApp

Tags: html, api, plugin

Quiero crear un código *HTML* para introducir en mi página para generar un enlace que vayan directo a *WhatsApp*.

Tengo esto hasta el momento:

```
<form target="mainFrame" method="get" action="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=573183271054&text"="target="_blank">

<input type="number" name="phone" value="">
<input type="text" name="text" value="">
<input type="submit" name="" value="Buscar">

</form>
```

El problema es que cuando el texto ingresado contiene más de una frase, se rellena con `+`.

Está quedando así:

```
https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=17862013838&text=Hola+quiero+info
```

... y para que funcione debería quedar así:

```
https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=17862013838&text=Hola%20quiero%20info
```

Algo similar a:

- https://instapaginas.com/generador-de-enlaces-de-whatsapp/

Answer (score 0):

Normalmente los links de Whatsapp van en una etiqueta  dentro de la etiqueta  iria el codigo que te esta generando para que mandes a tu numero de whatsapp el mensaje que le mandes ahi dentro de la etiqueta va el  ahi el icono no whatsapp.

En tu caso veo que le quieres pasar un formulario y no creo que te sirva mucho eso, te adjunto una pagina donde hay un icono de Whatsapp estatico que te podrias guiar [reymar.com](https://reymar.com.pe/)

Aqui es donde al hacer click en el icono te manda un mensaje que por defecto he ingresado y si el usuario quiere mandarle otro mensaje, al abrir web Whatsapp puede hacerlo.

Answer (score 0):

Tendrás que formatear el valor antes de enviarlo.

```js
function onSubmit(event){
  event.preventDefault(); 
  // almacenar el valo
  var value = event.target[1].value; 
  // formatea el valor a enviar
  event.target[1].value = encodeURI(value); 
  // envia el formulario
  event.target.submit(); 
  // restaurar el valor anterior (Esto es para que no se vea el valor formateado)
  event.target[1].value = value
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="onSubmit(event)" target="mainFrame" method="get" action="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=573183271054&text" target="_blank">

  <input type="number" name="phone" value="">
  <input type="text" name="text" value="">
  <input type="submit" name="" value="Buscar">

</form>
```

por cierto en `event.target[1]`, el 1 hace referencia al orden de los inputs comenzando por 0.

input[type=number] = 0

input[type=text] = 1

input[type=submit] = 2

Puedes eliminar la funcion, y colocarla directamente en el html

```
<form onsubmit="
      event.preventDefault(); 
      // almacenar el valo
      var value = event.target[1].value; 
      // formatea el valor a enviar
      event.target[1].value = encodeURI(value); 
      // envia el formulario
      event.target.submit(); 
      // restaurar el valor anterior (Esto es para que no se vea el valor formateado)
      event.target[1].value = value

" target="mainFrame" method="get" action="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=573183271054&text" target="_blank">

    <input type="number" name="phone" value="">
    <input type="text" name="text" value="">
    <input type="submit" name="" value="Buscar">

</form>
```